# Is it possible to get all the objects referencing a given object in Python?

Tags: python

I have a certain object `obj`
What I want is to get all the other objects referencing it. I know that I can get a reference count as `sys.getrefcount(obj)`, but that's not of much use in my case - I need the actual referencing objects, although I'm not sure that's even possible in Python...

Also, getting the line of code that created the object isn't of much use to me either - I know, where the object was created - I just don't know who is referencing it at the moment.

P.S. I need this to debug a leak.

Comment: I don't think Python keeps a list of the actual references; probably _no_ reference-counting language keeps such a list.

Comment: @lanzz: Don't forget that CPython isn't purely reference-counted. It has a secondary garbage collector that deals with reference cycles.

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? Suppose you find out this information; what do you propose to do with it?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: If I find that out, then I'll know where the reference to the object wasn't deleted (but should have been) and can investigate, why it wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `gc` module. This is the closest you can get.

A good site is, e.g., [this one](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/gc/).

Comment: I guess `gc.get_referrers` is pretty much what I'm looking for. I don't know, how I overlooked that. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. If this helps you, please mark this as the solution so it doesn't show up in the "unanswered" section anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea: If you know where the object is created, I can imagine that you know the potential variables and classes that can have a reference to your object. So you may be able to use the [`id`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) function to check who is referencing what.

I hope it helps

Comment: The data structure I'm dealing with is quite complex and changing constantly with a lot of pickling and unpickling going on, so tracking by IDs would get really messy, besides I might not be aware of some of the possible referrers (there's just way to much code, to know it all)

Comment: Ok, I understand. That was just an idea.